# Powershell: Secure String 'Encryption Key' Usage --- Join-Domain Script

Tags: string, security, powershell, dns, key

I work in an enterprise environment, where I manage a lab of 75 computers. I use Ghost to image and then I walk the computers afterwards to change the PC names and SIDs.

I am implementing a script to automatically add the computers to the domain but I am new to PowerShell and would really appreciate the help. Here's the script I'm using, 1.ps1:

```
    Param (
    [String]$User = $(Throw "MYDOMAINUSERINFO"),
     [String]$Domain = "MYDOMAININFO",
     [String]$PathToCred = "C:\OMC\AutoPost"
     ) 

    #Make sure our path string has a trailing backslash
    If ($PathToCred[$PathToCred.Length - 1] -ne "\")
    {    $PathToCred += "\"
    }

    #Now create file string
    $File = $PathToCred + "JoinDomain-$User.crd"

    #And find out if it's there, if not create it
    If (-not (Test-Path $File))
    {    (Get-Credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $File
    }

    #Load the credential file
    $Password = Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($User,$Password)

    #Add the computer to the domain
    Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credential
```

I run this script using a batch file that I place in the startup folder.

```
   Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\OMC\AutoPost\1.ps1 -User MYDOMAINUSERINFO -Domain MYDOMAININFO -PathToCred C:\OMC\AutoPost\
```

Running this script works normally, it creates a credential file, reads the credential file, and joins the domain. Running this script after ghosting and walking does not work, I get the error:

```
    Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

I think this is because the computer knows that something has changed. I am using the same user account to add to the domain as I built the credentials with initially, so I believe that the computer is rejecting these credentials because the SID has changed.

I read online that I can use [-key Byte[]] to set a standard encryption key, which will allow me to get around this error. I'm too new at PowerShell to know how to use this, can anyone help me out?

More info:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849814.aspx

http://ss64.com/ps/convertfrom-securestring.html

Comment: Why are you using Ghost (on non-sysprepped machines) instead of WDS and MDT (kinda the standard MS deployment tools) : with MDT doing an auto domain join is easy. Extra benefits are endless : database support voor automatic deployments with specific settings, software installation and other nice stuff. (WDS is a standard windows server role and MDT is free). In a lot of cases people look for a technical solution to circumvent issues where they should actually look at the work process and refine that.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell SecureString is encrypted with the encrypting user as encryption key, which means that other users cannot decrypt it, however you can specify a different key when encrypting and use it again for decryption, of course it's not secure, but this is your decision.

To Create the Credential and export it to a file:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$Key = [byte]1..16
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $Key | Set-Content $File
```

To Load it Update your Script section

```
#Load the credential file

$Key = [byte]1..16
$Password = Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($User,$Password)
```

Comment: What is the formatting to use $Key = [byte]1..16?
I read that the key should be 24 digits. Is this necessary? Theoretically, can I use:
$Key = [byte]1

 - - - Also holy cow thank you, I'll test it.